# Retrieving SendGrid stats to show open and click rates of email sent by a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am trying to figure out a way to parse the sendgrid data to show a batch of emails with their open and click through rates on the front end of an app. Is this possible directly Sendgrid? I have read that it's better to use a third party service to parse through the data.

Ideally, I'd just like to show something similiar to the sendgrid activity feed from a specific category (email, open, click)

Answer (score 2):

The SendGrid activity feed is a paid add-on available to certain high volume users, or as a paid on. You're probably looking for this: https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/email_activity_feed.html

But they say:

> In order to gain access to the Email Activity Feed API, you must purchase additional email activity history.

Another alternative is to keep track of every outgoing email ID and parse all their Event Webhooks to build these stats yourself, by keeping track of the webhook events in your own database.

Or you could use a third party [provider-agnostic email API](https://www.flutemail.com/) like Flute.